# Having some trouble inserting lines in the middle of a Linux file using SED

Tags: linux, sed

Sorry to say but I am really new to all of this and I've tried using available resources to get this done, but I'm doing something wrong.

What I want to do is to add these two lines to the /etc/security/limits.conf file BEFORE the `#End of line` tag at the bottom.

```
tcserver soft nproc 32368
tcserver hard nproc 32368
```

As there may be information in here already for the multiple machines I want to push this out to, using the last line seems the best option if pushing out from Satellite.

I imagine that sed is the best option for this.  I tried to do it as the following but it comes back as a failure when I push.

```
sed '/^#$/{N; /# End of file/i\
tcserver soft nproc 32368\
tcserver hard nproc 32368\
}' /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^# End of file *$/ i\
tcserver soft nproc 32368\
tcserver hard nproc 32368
' /etc/security/limits.conf
```

- space around i is important (on posix version, GNU sed is more tolerant on this)
- a back space on each line from `i` until last line to add but not on this last line (or you add the following line littearly and this is a sed instruction)

I just add the delimiter around the search pattern to exclude any other line that include this (comment for example)

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/# End of file/tcserver soft nproc 32368\ntcserver hard nproc 32368\n# End of file/' /etc/security/limits.conf`
i belive that should do the trick (and it is pretty strightforward)

`-i` to do it 'in place'

also remember that to modify files in /etc dir you may need root access

Comment: he dosen't want to replace, he want to add before # End of file

Comment: yep thats, what im proposing here - look closely on my `sed` proposal please - i 'replace' `# End of file` with three lines: what he want to insert and **then** `# End of file` so it basically is "adding before"